# How to show GUI for a jsonc (json with comment) in VS Code?

Tags: json, user-interface, visual-studio-code

I am developing an extension for VS Code. And I want to add a command in my extension to show a jsonc file with GUI, just like the command "Open Settings (UI)" in VS Code. But seems there is no API to open a jsonc file like this. VS code can only open a jsonc file directly.

I also take a quick look of VS Code source code, but found it's very complex to do so. Are there any other methods to implement this? Or third-party package?

Comment: write an extension for this with a `Webview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the source code of VS Code and also source code of C/C++ extension (Microsoft), the resolution would be use WebView. You need to handle the HTML page your self and use vscode.window.createWebViewPanel to create the web page. If you want to parse jsonc, you can use npm package jsonc-parser. Seems this is the only method for now.
For others reference. This question can be closed now.